# Play audio from video when phone is on silent mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am building an application that plays certain video files.  However, when the phone is on vibrate the audio still plays.  Apps like youtube still play the audio form their videos when the phone is on vibrate.  How can I do this?  I am using avplayer to play the video. Below is my code for playing the video

```
_player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:pi];
AVPlayerViewController *playerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
playerController.player = _player;
[self presentViewController:playerController animated:YES completion:nil];
playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[_player setMuted:false];
[self addChildViewController:playerController];
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution.  Adding this code allows whatever video is playing to produce audio even on silent mode.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
 setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
 error: nil];
```

Comment: This works even I'm using `WebView` to host an `<iframe>` of YouTube video. Thanks.